# Can't find variable: AppRegistry in case it is not used anywhere

Tags: react-native

> Why am I receiving this error in case I don't use AppRegistry anywhere
>   in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Check index.js file in root of your project it has AppRegistry you might have deleted its import
if that's the case

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'
```

Comment: I found where was the mistake. Thank you